Playwright HTTP proxy Authentication issue
I am using playwright java lib 1.44 version.
I am setting proxy url, username & password in Proxy object provided in launch options. But some how apache traffic proxy server is not able to authenticate it. Its debug logs does not show username/password in request headers which were meant for proxy server.
I am using following code to launch browser..
launchOptions.setProxy(new Proxy("http://proxy:8080/"));
launchOptions.proxy.setUsername("abcUser");
launchOptions.proxy.setPassword("123456");
Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch(launchOptions);

Question:

In which request header playwright sets the authentication information ? header name ?

Is there anyway to view this header information?

Does playwright converts this proxy info internally into "Proxy-Authorization" : encoded("abcUser:123456") ?

shall i set it as follows? Is this required?


String proxyEncoding = Base64Encoder.encode ("abcUser:123456");
page.setExtraHTTPHeaders(Map.of("Proxy-Authorization", proxyEncoding));

Please share the full error message as text.

@ggorlen: I do not see any error message in java app, it just timesout..
On proxy server side, its not getting authenticated, thats what I think as the request is not passing thro proxy, when enabled debug level on proxy server, could not see username/password in request header.

Thanks for confirming. Timeouts are errors, aren't they? A [mcve] would be useful here.
